# Handle changeable key/value pairs in RestKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm building a news feed feature in an iPhone app. It uses RestKit to fetch data from the server (JSON) that is running rails and I'm using the gem PublicActivity to create the feed items.

Connected to each news feed item is a list of custom key/values. I don't want to map these in RestKit and attributes in Core Data as these change for each feed item type.

What is the best way to handle this?

1. How to transfer the custom key/value data within the JSON response?
2. How do I handle the key/values in RestKit and Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to place all of the custom / arbitrary key/value pairs into their own dictionary, where that dictionary has a static key in the JSON. In Core Data, create a corresponding attribute of `transformable` type. In your RestKit code, create a standard mapping from the source to the destination key.

In this way, RestKit will take the source dictionary and place it straight into Core Data, and from your managed object you can get the dictionary and use whatever you require from it.